# Get Identity Value from Typed DataSet

Tags: c#, ms-access, dataset, typed-dataset

I got a typed dataset in my form.  Using BindingSource to walk in rows, inserting and updating records.

Everything is fine but I need inserted records identity value for generating a string for my `GeneratedCode` field in my table.

After getting this value I'll send value to my `CodeGen()` method and generate string, and update same row's `CodeGen` field with this value.

I'm using Access database. I know there is that `@@Identity` thing for Access, but how can I use it? I don't want to use `OleDbCommand` or something like this.

How can I do that?

```
  string GenCode(int pCariId)
    {
        string myvalue;
        int totalDigit = 7;

        myvalue = "CR" + pCariId.ToString();
        for (int digit = myvalue.Length; digit <= totalDigit - 1; digit++)
        {
            myvalue = myvalue.Insert(2, "0");

        }
        return myvalue;
    }

private void dataNavigator_ButtonClick(object sender, NavigatorButtonClickEventArgs e)
    {
         switch (e.Button.ButtonType)
        {
            case NavigatorButtonType.EndEdit:
                try
                {

                    this.Validate();

                    if (KaydetFlags == 1)
                    {
                        this.bndCariKayit.EndEdit();

                        datagate_muhasebeDataSet.TB_CARI.Rows[datagate_muhasebeDataSet.Tables["TB_CARI"].Rows.Count - 1]["INS_USR"] = 0;
                        datagate_muhasebeDataSet.TB_CARI.Rows[datagate_muhasebeDataSet.Tables["TB_CARI"].Rows.Count - 1]["INS_TRH"] = DateTime.Now;
                        XtraMessageBox.Show("Yeni Cari Kaydı Tamamlandı.");
                        KaydetFlags = 0;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        DataRowView currentRow = (DataRowView)bndCariKayit.Current;
                        currentRow.Row["UPD_USR"] = "0";
                        currentRow.Row["UPD_TRH"] = DateTime.Now;
                        XtraMessageBox.Show("Cari Kaydı Güncellendi.");
                        this.bndCariKayit.EndEdit();
                    }
                    this.tB_CARITableAdapter.Update(datagate_muhasebeDataSet.TB_CARI);


                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    XtraMessageBox.Show("Kayıt İşlemi Başarısız. Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz.");
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  you have to use `RowUpdated` method of your `TableAdapter`

```
private static void OnRowUpdated(
  object sender, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Conditionally execute this code block on inserts only.
    if (e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmdNewID = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY",
            connection);
        // Retrieve the Autonumber and store it in the CategoryID column.
        e.Row["CategoryID"] = (int)cmdNewID.ExecuteScalar();
        e.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;
    }
}
```

Another option, which I actually use is to create `Select` query which simply gets maximum value from you `id` column:

```
SelectLastAddedId:
SELECT MAX(id) FROM obmiar
```

Just set query execute mode to `scalar` and you can refer to it in your code as 
`int lastId =` `TableAdapter.SelectLastAddedId()`